# How to get order article image

Tags: shopware

I am creating a custom plugin, which display order information if a customer enter an **order number** and **zip code**. My problem is when an article has variants, then it's outputing multiple times the same article, and I think it's because the joing I'm doing to the **s_articles_img** table **(to get the image from the ordered article and also if it's a variant article)**, has multiple times the same value stored, in this case, the **articleID**.

The leftjoin I have:

```
->leftJoin('a', 's_articles_img', 'f', 'f.articleID = e.articleID')
```

I tested with a local shopware installation and the demo data, it has an article named **Variantenartikel** which is a t-shirt with variants in size and color. So the **s_article_img** table has 3 times the same **articleID** (5) for shirt, shirt_red and shirt_blue.

So my question is: **How can I only get the ones I need?** I tried to find the relation between tables, but can't see where. I checked **the s_order_details table, s_media**, etc. But there's no relation between those tables.

Am I missing something?

Here is my complete query builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->container->get('dbal_connection')->createQueryBuilder(); 
$queryBuilder->select('a.id', 'a.userID', 'a.ordernumber', 'a.ordertime', 'b.zipcode as bzipcode', 'b.firstname as bfirstname', 'b.lastname as blastname', 'b.customernumber', 'b.street', 'b.city', 'd.zipcode as dzipcode', 'd.firstname as dfirstname', 'd.lastname as dlastname', 'e.name', 'e.price', 'e.articleID', 'e.articleordernumber', 'f.img', 'f.extension', 'g.email', 'g.salutation', 'h.status')
          ->from('s_order', 'a')
          ->leftJoin('a', 's_order_billingaddress', 'b', 'a.id = b.orderID')
          ->leftJoin('a', 's_order_documents', 'c', 'a.id = c.orderID')
          ->leftJoin('a', 's_order_shippingaddress', 'd', 'a.id = d.orderID')
          ->leftJoin('a', 's_order_details', 'e', 'a.id = e.orderID')

          ->leftJoin('a', 's_articles_img', 'f', 'f.articleID = e.articleID')

          ->leftJoin('a', 's_user', 'g', 'g.id = a.userID')
          ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('a.ordernumber', ':ordernumber'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.docID', ':ordernumber')
           ))
          ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('b.zipcode', ':bzipcode'),
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('d.zipcode', ':bzipcode')
           ))
          ->andWhere('d.orderID = a.id')
          //->andWhere('h.orderNumber = a.ordernumber')
          ->setParameter('ordernumber', $idNumber)
          ->setParameter('bzipcode', $zipcode);
```

I am not an expert in database queries so if this one is not really accurate I apologies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function to get the variant specific cover image: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/512cc0ff59c431bbf0d1e968ec0b435e38a576ab/engine/Shopware/Core/sArticles.php#L1758

Something like this:

```
$article = Shopware()->Modules()->Articles()->sGetArticleById($position['articleID']);
$article = Shopware()->Modules()->Articles()->sGetConfiguratorImage($article);
```

When you only need the cover image, this function would do the same: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/512cc0ff59c431bbf0d1e968ec0b435e38a576ab/engine/Shopware/Core/sArticles.php#L1265

The image/option relation is saved in the s_article_img_mapping_rules. When the image has a mapping this is saved in s_article_img_mappings. It should be a quite heavy SQL statement to get from the article to the image:

s_article_details.id -> s_article_configurator_option_relations.option_id -> s_article_img_mapping_rules.mapping_id -> s_article_img_mappings.image_id -> s_article_img.id

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am going to try it and see :)

Comment: So, I tried the sample you wrote above and it displays the main article image, as you are passing the articleID. But in my case I need to get the variant image, because the articleID is the same for all the variants. I tried the other function "Shopware()->Modules()->Articles()->getArticleCover" and passed the articleID and articleordernumber but then I get an error "Call to a member function getSettings() on null in" Probably because I didn't pass the $articlealbum parameter. How can I get the $articlealbum?

Comment: I found another way, using Shopware()->Modules()->Articles()->sGetProductByOrdernumber() displays an object which contains the path to the variant image. So I mark this response as the solution anyways because it helped me to clarify the way shopware handle the data and how to get it.